# P4V: Find the most recent changelist that affects a given workspace?

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is there a command-line way to find the most recent changelist that affects a given workspace? This can be done in the GUI by (in the workspaces tab), right-clicking the tip of the workspace tree, then going to "Folder History", and sorting by timestamp.

Thank you much and I greatly appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `p4 changes` command ([usage](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/changes.html#1048020)).

`p4 changes -t -l -c YOUR_WORKSPACE -m 1 -s submitted //depot/project/...`

Almost anything that can be done in P4V is achievable via the commandline (that is one of the best things about P4 is that is commandline *first*, *gui* second).

Comment: This will return changes submitted *from* the workspace, but not changes that apply *to* the workspace that were submitted from other workspaces.  I.e. it's changes *effected by* the workspace, not changes that *affect* the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to this depends on what you mean by "changelist that affects a given workspace".  Do you mean:

1. Changelist that *modifies* a given workspace definition?  (There's no such thing.)
2. Changelist whose contents are currently synced to the workspace?  (`p4 changes -m1 @workspace`)
3. Changelist whose contents COULD be synced to the workspace?  (`p4 changes -m1 //workspace/...` -- this is the one that corresponds to the P4V operation you describe)